# How to make clipping mask out of these objects/similar solution. It says "Can't make clipping path"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask

So I have this [image: object]

I'm trying to make the sadow only appear on the right side of the petals, and the petals only, so the background stays white. However, I can't make a clipping mask out of the blend path (the shadow) and the petals, since it says "Can't make clipping mask"

How should I achieve this?

Comment: The mask must be the top object. Also, a path or a compound path. Otherwise you will receive that warning.

Answer (score 1):

The blend is hundreds of separate paths . A clipping path is one simple or compound path. The blend is on top of the petal.Clipping must come after the objects it is clipping. Objects that come after other objects appear above the objects in the layer tree.

So simply your asking blend to clip the petal. This will not work, a blend is not one path. Move the blend below the petal that you intend to use as clipping then it will allow you to do this.